# How not to display old subscription values in the app store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

My application had updated **subscription prices**.

However, in the details of our app in the app store, you can still see **all existing subscription prices**.

The question is: How can I make **visible only the prices we charge today**?

----- **edit** -----

If I uncheck the "Cleared for Sale" as @PaulSchröder suggest.

When **old subscribers** complete their subscription time. Will they be able to **automatically renew** (old price) or will they **be canceled** (since this subscription no longer exists)?

[image: Prices in App Store]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to your subscription in App Store Connect and uncheck the "Cleared for Sale" checkbox (it is next to the Product-id). Unfortunately this can only do the Account Holder.

According to [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125213) from PBK in Apples developer forum (third post), after unchecking the checkbox, it should open a dialog stating the following:

> Your in-app purchase will be removed from sale on the App Store and discontinued as an auto-renewable subscription. Existing subscribers won’t be able to renew this subscription. To view the number of existing subscribers, go to Sales and Trends.
>   By selecting this checkbox and clicking Remove from Sale, you agree to provide the full amount of content to eligible subscribers through November 30, 2019. If you’re unable to do this, you allow Apple to refund the full amount or portion of the price paid by the user for that subscription.

So old subscribers will be affected in the way that their subscription won't re-new.

Comment: If I uncheck the "Cleared for Sale". Old subscribers will not be affected?

Comment: They will be affected because their subscription won't be renewed after it expires. After their subscription expired, they have to subscribe to a different subscription manually.